# opening excel file in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

So here is code

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\a.xls")
print(x)
```

and output:

```
==================== RESTART: C:/Users/User/Desktop/sheet.py ===================
       SNo                Country  ... Unnamed: 5  Unnamed: 6
0      1.0   United Arab Emirates  ...        NaN         NaN
1      2.0                Nigeria  ...        NaN         NaN
2      3.0                  Ghana  ...        NaN         NaN
3      4.0       Pitcairn Islands  ...        NaN         NaN
4      5.0               Ethiopia  ...        NaN        51.0
..     ...                    ...  ...        ...         ...
254    NaN                    NaN  ...        NaN         NaN
255  241.0               Cameroon  ...        NaN         NaN
256  242.0                  Nauru  ...        NaN         NaN
257  243.0                Armenia  ...        NaN         NaN
258  244.0                Croatia  ...        NaN         NaN

[259 rows x 7 columns]
>>>
```

file that i try to open has like 260 rows and it only shows  this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you count the heading ? Use the following to check last row with your excel last row.

> x.iloc[-1]

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
df = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\a.xls")
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', df.shape[0]+1)
print(df)
```

Comment: i I tried and it didnt work. here is code                                                                           
   import pandas as pd


pd = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\a.xls")
pd.set_option( 'display.max_rows' , df.shape[0]+1)
print(df)
 here is error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'set_option'

Comment: @MichałWisełka  try this  import pandas as pd
 df = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\a.xls") 
 df.set_option( 'display.max_rows' , df.shape[0]+1)
 print(df)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\a.xls") 
 df.set_option( 'display.max_rows' , df.shape[0]+1)
 print(df)
```